# org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: is happening while querying from localhost:8047

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2, apache-drill

I am getting the following exception only accessing my HDFS through a web page and the same is working fine with sqlLine from Terminal.

```
Query Failed: An Error Occurred
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: VALIDATION ERROR: From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 46: Table 'HDFSBolt-1-0-1489176215720.txt' not found SQL Query null [Error Id: b22f324a-456e-4a1c-bvfce-43a7b134daad on localhost:31010
```

Commands I tried for the above query:

```
1.use dfs.root;
2.select * from `HDFSBolt-1-0-1489176215720.txt` limit 10;
```

My storage plugin is as follows:

```
{
  "type": "file",
  "enabled": true,
  "connection": "hdfs://localhost:9000/",
  "config": null,
  "workspaces": {
    "root": {
      "location": "/rajdata6",
      "writable": true,
      "defaultInputFormat": "null"
    }
  },
  "formats": {
    "csv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "txt"
      ],
      "delimiter": ";"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the storage alias before the table name.

```
select * from dfs.`HDFSBolt-1-0-1489176215720.txt` limit 10;
```